# mongoose queries are hanging after modifying schema

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I modified my schema, and now anytime mongoose tries to run a query, it just hangs. Even worse, I put the schema back to normal and it's still hanging. Is there some background process I need to kill? Put the code below, but as I said, this worked before. Changing it and then putting it back and it's still broken. And it's ALL queries, not just this one.

```
routes.route('/userInfo/:username')
    .get(async (req, res) => {


        res.send(await userModel.findOne(
            {username:req.params.username}).lean().exec());                
    })
```

Model setup

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    modelName = 'user',
    schemaDefinition = require('../schema/' + modelName),
    schemaInstance = mongoose.Schema(schemaDefinition),
    modelInstance = mongoose.model(modelName, schemaInstance);

module.exports = modelInstance
```

Schema

```
module.exports = {    
    username: String,
    email: String,
    firstName: String,
    lastName: String,
    createdOn: Date,
    updatedOn: Date,
    scopes: [String]
}
```

**Update**: I deleted the entire project and recloned it from github. It started working...wut. I tried deleting node_modules before. I restarted my computer. None of that worked. Why the crap did deleting the project work :(

I'm not sure if this matters, but my models are coming from an npm module that I pull from my github repo (I'm sharing it across a couple different projects).

Comment: Please post your code. How are we supposed to tell you what's wrong if you don't show what you have? Show your schema definition and the code that makes the query.

Comment: I've added the code, though I don't know if it'll be much help. This issue seems pretty...odd. No errors returned, no responses at all. After this starts, code that was working fine no longer works.

Comment: That does help, it's definitely better than nothing. Check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Let's confirm the obvious first, make sure the route is actually getting hit, and make sure there are no errors:

```
routes.route('/userInfo/:username').get((req, res) => {
  console.log(req.params);
  userModel.findOne({
    username: req.params.username
  }).lean().exec().then(data => {
    console.log(data);
    res.send(data);
  }, err => {
    console.log(err);
    res.status(500).send({ message: 'An error occurred' });
  });
});
```

I only know Express, I'm not familiar with whatever routing library you're using here but I'll just assume you did that part right unless someone else says otherwise.

Let me know what that gives you.

Comment: I've tried this and no beuno. Yes, the endpoint gets hit. As I've stated before, the code I have DID WORK. I changed the schema, and now it doesn't. The code didn't change. It's something with the interaction between mongoose and how it's expecting the collection to look?